# Data in the hierarchy with blanks in PANDAS change to fill the blank

Tags: python

There is data in the hierarchy with blanks in PANDAS.
The column means a category of the group and have a some blank cell.

I want to fill the blank, using a keep the same value until the next value comes.

for example

```
before

h10 h20 h30 h40
x   AAA w1  x1
        w2  xx
    BBB w3  rx
            rx
        w5  2x
y   CCC w6  rx
            r4
            t45

after

h10 h20 h30 h40
x   AAA w1  x1
x   AAA w2  xx
x   BBB w3  rx
x   BBB w3  rx
x   BBB w5  2x
y   CCC w6  rx
y   CCC w6  r4
y   CCC w6  t45
```

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'h10':  ['x','',"","","",'y',"",''],
    'h20':  ["AAA","","BBB","","","CCC","",""],
    'h30':  ['w1','w2','w3','','w5',"w6","",""],
    'h40':  ['x1',"xx","rx","rx",'2x','rx','r4','t45']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the empty string with `nan` values using a regex, then use `ffill` to forward fill the `nan` values.  The replace pattern `r'^$'` means the start of a string immediately followed by the end of a string, which will match an empty string.

```
import numpy as np

df.replace(r'^$', np.nan, regex=True).ffill()
# returns:
  h10  h20 h30  h40
0   x  AAA  w1   x1
1   x  AAA  w2   xx
2   x  BBB  w3   rx
3   x  BBB  w3   rx
4   x  BBB  w5   2x
5   y  CCC  w6   rx
6   y  CCC  w6   r4
7   y  CCC  w6  t45
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is ffill (forward fill). It will fill the blank values with the last seen value in the column.

```
df[‘h10’].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Alternatively, you can try bfill (backward fill), if that also comes up.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful. Thank you again for your help.